# FBML to get the share count of a link?

Tags: fbml

I need to get the number of likes for a given url.how to do it? 
also can i get the total fancounts of a fb page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Facebook's API. Just add the URL's you are interested in to the end of of this URL:**

`http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=`

**example:**

[http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=stackoverflow.com,serverfault.com](http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=stackoverflow.com,serverfault.com,superuser.com)

I think the fancount is just the "like" count of the URL for the FB page.

Source, with PHP code for parsing the output: [Get likes on urls from Facebook](http://www.sundh.com/blog/2010/11/get-likes-on-urls-from-facebook/)

Answer (score 2):

Address

> http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://facebook.com

returns:

> {"id": "http://facebook.com","shares": 54290530,"comments": 1244}

So to change id parametr for your URL and get your shares count via jQuery use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.getJSON(
        "http://graph.facebook.com",
        { id : "http://facebook.com" }, //here should be your URL
        function(json){
            //var data = jQuery.parseJSON();
            alert( json.shares );
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

FQL `link_stat` would be a nice alternative to rest API (facebook is in process of deprecating the REST API)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/